# Having Issue while publishing a flutter application to f-droid

Tags: android, flutter, gitlab, open-source, fdroid

Running `fdroid readmeta`  command shows this

```
/usr/bin/fdroid:141: DeprecationWarning: The 'warn' function is deprecated, use 'warning' instead
  logging.warn(_("Encoding is set to '{enc}' fdroid might run "
WARNING: Encoding is set to 'ISO8859-1' fdroid might run into encoding issues. Please set it to 'UTF-8' for best results.
WARNING: No 'config.py' found, using defaults.
CRITICAL: Unrecognised app field 'AllowedAPKSigningKeys' in 'metadata/InfinityLoop1309.NewPipeEnhanced.yml'
```

This error occurred after I removed srclib from YOUR-PROJECT-ID.yml and added submodules True; and added flutter submodule in the repo. As with srclib i was having checkupdates pipeline test fail in gitlab pipeline

I checked everywhere in the project, the encoding is set to 'UTF-8' but still shows error.
Also the .yml file it is showing in the error it is not related to my project, how to ignore this or resolve this issue.

I tried to reset everything to UTF-8 encoding in android studio and rechecked. it didn't work out.